# At what pressure is whipped cream stored in a can?

Tags: food-science, whipped-cream

Whipped cream is often sold in pressurized cans. At what pressure is the cream stored in such a can when it is new? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to know - just curiosity, or something specific you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: My guess is 2-3 atm but that is just a guess.  Kids (and adults) squirt directly in their mouth and don't blow out an ear so it cannot be very high.  They are pretty accurate at just having a little bit of gas left after the whip cream is empty.

Answer (score -2):

"... (50 bar of pressure) per charger."

according to http://creativewhip.com/isi-charging-system/

Comment: 50 bar is the pressure in the charger - the tiny canister of gas that you use to pressurize the much larger vessel that actually makes the whipped cream. So you'll end up with way less pressure there. Also, not necessarily the same as commercial canned whipped cream.